# How to count occurance of characters in string including variations, like upside-down characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sometimes we get text like reversed when people scan documents in reverse, which will look like this:

```
stri = "1234 ᔭƐᘔІ "
```

I would like to count occurance of the each number in this cases like.

```
1 - occured 2 times including reversed one.
2 - occured 2 times including reversed one
3 - occured 2 times including reversed one
4 - occured 2 times including reversed one
```

I've tried to use normal count like

```
stri.count('1')
```

which gives me 1, but I expected 2 including reversed.

Expected output

```
Number of 2's in str = 2
```

Comment: Why don't you use `stri.count('1') + stri.count('І')`?

Comment: what If i wnat to use count 2? like see my last expected output

Comment: Use `stri.count('2') + stri.count('ᘔ')`?

Comment: It will be amibigouse @mkrieger1 in this case so I need to create a separate map for every `128 ASCII characters`

Comment: Yes, I guess you will need to do that.

Comment: Yeah If i don't get any easy answers then I have to I guess

Comment: @Cookie check my solution too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give simple funny answer. Deal reversed charcters by reversing them

Install this - [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/upsidedown/#:%7E:text=Upsidedown%20is%20a%20simple%20Python,characters%20as%20encoded%20in%20Unicode.)

```
pip install upsidedown


import upsidedown

strs = "1234 ᔭƐᘔІ "

normal =(strs.count('1'))

flip = (upsidedown.transform('1234 ᔭƐᘔІ'))
flip = (flip.count('1'))

total = flip + normal
print(total)
```

output

```
2
```

Comment: Simple!!? I no need to create any maps?..Let me check

Comment: Yes, try this..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the characters that you are using aren't really flipped but they are some other `UNICODE` characters. Python, doesn't recognize `1` because it is `1`, but it rather recognized it by `UNICODES`. Therefore, there is no theoretical way to achieve this. However, here's a practical method:

```
# Create a dict with the matching values
string_and_reverse = {
    "1": ["1", "І"],
    "2": ["2", "ᘔ"],
    "3": ["3", "Ɛ"],
    "4": ["4", "ᔭ"],
} # and so on...
```

Then, change your code to:

```
stri= "1234 ᔭƐᘔІ "

def replace(stri:str, value:str):
    literal = string_and_reverse[value] # fetch values to replace
    count = 0
    for l in literal: # iterates through every value in the key
        count+= stri.count(l) # count the value and increments it
    return count
print(replace(stri, "1")) # just pass whatever you want to replace in place of "value"
```

Comment: The only possible methodology I could think of, which would however save you lines rather than `counting` all of them manually but to create a relation using a `dictionary`.

Comment: This will fial in some cases Myth like as you can see you map `6 -->'9'...Will endup wrong ocuurance when seraching for '9'`...Anyway nice solution +1 from my side

Comment: I'm checking this too...But As i said beofre  I need to create map for every `128` ASCII elemnts it is pain